# Html.TextBoxFor() not shown in view or shown as text when in field set

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 for editing model objects via Html.BeginForm(). The issue is when I pass the model object to be edited, the only part of view that renders properly is the `OK` button.
`Html.TextBoxFor()` does not show the input textbox in the View or shown as text when in fieldset, even if I added '@' before it.

Here's the code:

*AddEdit.cshtml*

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AddEdit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <fieldset>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Hero.Name);

                <input type="submit" value="OK" />
            </fieldset>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*And here's my controller class:*

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public string GetData()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {data = new HeroStorage().GetAllViewModels()});
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void Edit(AddEditViewModel model)
        {
            new HeroStorage().Update(model.Hero);
            RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
         
        //RETURNS THE VIEW
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
        {
            return View("AddEdit", new AddEditViewModel(){Hero = new HeroStorage().GetByID(ID), Studios = new StudioStorage().GetAll()});
        }

    }
```

Comment: You're redirecting to Index but index doesn't return an object to the view.

Comment: you're creating a new object of type HeroStorage(), and the .GetByID (I think) is returning nothing. if you're using a database as your model you should find it easier. Alternatively, you could use the scaffolding option which creates CRUD operations automatically on a given model.

Comment: the reason it doesn't render *anything* is because your model passed is empty, and hence will display nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would post this as a comment, but it wouldn't be readable/etc which i think you could make great use of. However, here is some of the **Auto generated** code from the framework:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Pot</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TrailerID)

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Pot)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Capacity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Capacity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Capacity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The main things to look here for are:

1. the use of `@Html.EditorFor(...`
2. an `AntiForgeryToken`
3. I'm using EF

The `[HttpPost]` method for the Edit:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "TrailerID,Pot,Capacity,Comments")] tbl_Pot tbl_Pot)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tbl_Pot).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(tbl_Pot);
        }
```

PS/Disclaimer: Please do not worry about the naming of my tbl/entries, as these refer to a fuel system, not any other kind of 'Pot'

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because after updating the content in the Post Method of Edit, you are redirecting to `INDEX` which in return do not pass any model to the view so, the `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Hero.Name)` is empty.

UPDATE:

Eventually the problem was fixed by changing `TextBoxFor` to `EditorFor`

Comment: that's the post event - OP is asking *'why can't i view it in AddEdit view'*

Comment: @jbutler483 that's what I said `RedirectToAction("Index");` and then Index returns `return View();` so she is not passing any model at this time

Comment: Again, are we not looking at the `[HttpGet]` action method, while you're looking at the `[HttpPost]` Method - OP hasn't hit 'OK' and so the `[HttpGet]` Method is the first part to render - They haven't been able to *physically edit* it yet...

Comment: The question is about "why i see just 'Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Hero.Name);' but not my textbox?" Index() not so important

Comment: @Julia I *think* i understand you now - try using `@Html.EditorFor(...` and see if that's what you mean.

Comment: @jbutler483 but @html.TextBoxFor( should work as well

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee i'm just looking at what the framework creates automatically (from scaffold) - I know it for **definite** that this *should* work since it's made already.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser is this?
Your code seems to work in IE 11 and Chrome - i.e. I've just copy/paste it and received the text box. However, I'd like to mention the following:

1. Loose the semi-colon after the `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Hero.Name)`. 
   You don't need that in a Razor expression.
2. `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Hero.Name)` refers to unknown object named "model".
   Remember that the property, which refers to the actual model is
   `Model`, not "model". I'd recommend changing
   `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Hero.Name)` to
   `@Html.TextBoxFor(**heroName** => **M**odel.Hero.Name)`. Semantically it
   will be more correct & readable.
3. Do you have _Layout.cshtml in your project?
   If so, why you are structuring the whole HTML in AddEdit.cshtml?
   That way the HTML rendered to the browser becomes invalid and may be
   some browser(s) don't (can't) parse it. 
   If you're using _Layout.cshtml, loose everything but the BODY content in AddEdit.cshtml
   Do HEAD editions in _Layout.cshtml